# ORDERBY 'Incorrect Syntax' in Declare Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I'm trying to do such a simple task, yet it's driving me crazy how it keeps failing.

```
DECLARE @neighbour HierarchyId = (SELECT [stPath] as tmpPath
                                  FROM [DEV].[tmp].[StrategyTable] t  
                                  WHERE ParentCode = 'TOP') 
                                  ORDER BY t.stKey DESC;
```

I keep getting an error saying

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
```

At the same time, it works for something WITHOUT a where clause; like

```
DECLARE @parent HierarchyId = (SELECT 
                            [stPath] AS tmpPath
                            FROM [DEV].[tmp].[StrategyTable] t WHERE [ParentCode] = 'TOP')
```

WTF.......

Comment: The second isn't without a `WHERE` clause, it is without an `ORDER BY` outside the `()`.

Comment: Does it work if you move the `ORDER BY` _inside_ the `(SELECT...)` subselect?

Comment: you probably also need a `TOP 1` with that `order by` to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @neighbour HierarchyId = (SELECT TOP 1 [stPath] as tmpPath
                                  FROM [DEV].[tmp].[StrategyTable] t  
                                  WHERE ParentCode = 'TOP' 
                                  ORDER BY t.stKey DESC);
```

This should accomplish what you want.